# How to do translation via csv file imported from PHP my admin

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm experimenting with a variety of modules to translate, but I find that a simple CSV file would be best.

TMGMT doesn't work for me as I get a lot of bugs that I can't resolve.

Is there a way to translate from CSV export from PHP my admin, translate and then re-import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trnslate `Po` files with  [POEDitor](https://poedit.net/) but if you insist use `csv` 
I suggest you use [csv2po](http://translate-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/using_csv2po.html) , export drupal translate in `po` file, convert `po` file to `csv` translate them in excel (or anywhere you want) then convert back it to `po` and import it to your site.

some quote from its documentation

> csv2po allows you to create CSV files from PO files. This allows you
>   to send translation work to translators who do not or cannot use PO
>   Editors but who can use a Spreadsheet.
>
> po2csv allows you to send CSV files, which can be edited in any
>   spreadsheet, to a translator. This document outlines the process to
>   follow from the raw po files -> CSV files -> back to PO. We also look
>   at a case where you may have submitted a subset of the PO files for
>   translation and you need to integrate these.

Comment: I found an easier solution at https://localise.biz/free/poeditor  , however.  The PO files on https://localize.drupal.org/download are core. I want to translate fields, content , views ect... how do I import and export PO files of that type in Drupal?

Comment: @BrunoVincent I think you dont want use po and want csv only,if you want po editor I suggest you install   https://poedit.net/

Comment: Yes, poedit is fine. How do I import and export PO fiiles from inside drupal?   Not sure how drupal works, if I add fields in English, and I have translation in say French, will that field be added to PO french file? Then I export PO french file, translate, and import it back into Drupal? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: @BrunoVincent by default you have  tools to export and import translate data as `po` file . 
admin/config/regional/translate/import  ,and  

admin/config/regional/translate/export

Comment: Excellent advice, exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I wasted a week and hours and hours trying to get a whole bunch of complexe modules to do this...;(   But one more question, when exporting there are many options, but multiple select is not available, is it possible to bulk export for example, views, contact, fields ect...in one file?

Comment: @BrunoVincent sometimes the solution is too easier that we think :D.
you can get help form  https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt and https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation_export_import

Comment: TMGMT, views, BEF mixed together...= buggs and multiple patches in my case, but will give drupal.org/project/entity_translation_export_import a try, thks zhilevan

Comment: @BrunoVincent you're welcome, :) we are here to help each other